# Internal microphone not detected: 20.04, HP Envy x360, Ryzen 5 4500

Tags: sound, 20.04, pulseaudio, hp, microphone

I'm very new to Linux -- as in, installed Ubuntu for the first time this week. I've run up against an issue that I'm totally stuck on. In **Settings - Sound** my output device is detected, but my input device is not, meaning e.g. my voice cannot be heard on webcam videos etc.

My laptop is an HP Envy x360, with Ryzen 5 4500 CPU. I have a dual boot, also running Windows 10. Within Windows my microphone is detected and works fine.

I'm very much finding my way with this, but I've followed the steps in 2.1 here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Microphone_not_detected_by_PulseAudio

```
arecord -l
```

produced:

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC245 Analog [ALC245 Analog]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

So according to the Arch Linux page my sound card is called

```
hw:1,0
```

I then followed the instructions and edited `/etc/pulse/default.pa` by entering `load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:1,0` here:

```
### Automatically load driver modules depending on the hardware available
.ifexists module-udev-detect.so
load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:1,0
load-module module-udev-detect
.else
```

In PulseAudio volume controls I now have an input device:

[image: PulseAudio input]

But no input device under **Settings - Sounds** and still no working microphone

I have also tried following the steps here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1840725

I install and run `hdajackretask`. When I try to override unconnected pin 12 and click Apply I get this error message:

[image: tee: /sys/class/sound/hwC1D0/reconfig: Device or resource busy]

I have followed the advice on [the Ubuntu wiki PulseAudio page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio)

To reset user config I entered:

```
rm -r ~/.config/pulse; pulseaudio -k
```

And logged off and back on. I now have a microphone detected (progress!)... but no sound is recorded...

EDIT 23/6

I've made some progress, but still no working microphone.

I used `hdajackretask` to set Black Mic, Left side Pin ID:0x19 to internal mic, selected Override and Install boot override.

I was then able to select Analogue Stereo Duplex in Config - Profile in PulseAudio. Previously this was 'unavailable'.

Now, the weird bit... When sound is playing on my laptop, from music or notifications etc, the monitor bar of the microphone in PulseAudio responds, showing that it is detecting a signal. However, when I speak in to it, no joy. And if I record audio from the command line, the audio file is silent e.g.

```
sudo arecord -f S16_LE -c 2 -d 5 -r 44100 --device="hw:1,0" /tmp/test-mic.wav
aplay /tmp/test-mic.wav
```

EDIT: 24/6

In response to comment below, this is the Alsa mixer, nothing looks untoward as far as I can see?

[image: Alsa mixer]

Answer (score 1):

this device uses digital mics and the one you selected in hdajackretask is the 3.5mm Jack in the Left Side of the device, not the internal digital one.

I think the SOF-Firmware Driver should be the solution to your problem.

Comment: That sounds promising, thanks. Looks like this is hosted on Git-Hub? Could you explain how I would go about installing this, for a total new-comer?

Comment: Do I need to clone and build this whole thing? https://github.com/thesofproject/linux

Comment: Normaly downloading the firmware from the releases and moving them to /lib/firmware/intel/sof/ should be all you have to do if i'm not mistaken. There are some Guides for Lenovo Notebooks with SOF out there you can try.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was also a custom kernel. I have a recent HP Envy laptop (HP ENVY x360 Laptop - 15z-ds100) with a Ryzen 4700u Renoir processor and running ubuntu 20.04. To get the internal microphone to work I build the most recent kernel and went into menuconfig and navigated to device drivers -> sound card support -> Advanced linux sound architecture -> ALSA for SoC audio suport. I enabled AMD Audio Coprocessor - renoir support and AMD Renoir support for DMIC as a module.

```
$ grep -i renoir .config
CONFIG_SND_SOC_AMD_RENOIR=m
CONFIG_SND_SOC_AMD_RENOIR_MACH=m
```

Instructions for building kernel packages can be found here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam/GitKernelBuild

after booting the microphone works

```
uname -a
Linux envy15 5.8.0-rc4-custom #1 SMP Fri Jul 10 11:36:25 EDT 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

note the driver snd_rn_pci_acp3x is being used by device AMD Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor. Before it says N/A.

```
$ inxi -Fxxxz
System:    Kernel: 5.8.0-rc4-custom x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: Gnome 3.36.3 
           wm: gnome-shell dm: GDM3 3.34.1 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Convertible System: HP product: HP ENVY x360 Convertible 15-ds1xxx v: N/A 
           serial: <filter> Chassis: type: 31 serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: HP model: 87A9 v: 27.16 serial: <filter> UEFI: AMI v: F.03 date: 05/25/2020 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 4.0 Wh condition: 56.6/56.6 Wh (100%) volts: 13.8/15.1 
           model: 333-AC-31-A SA04055XL type: Li-ion serial: <filter> status: Discharging 
           Device-1: hid-0018:04F3:29CD.0001-battery model: ELAN2514:00 04F3:29CD serial: N/A 
           charge: N/A status: N/A 
CPU:       Topology: 8-Core model: AMD Ryzen 7 4700U with Radeon Graphics bits: 64 type: MCP 
           arch: Zen rev: 1 L2 cache: 4096 KiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm bogomips: 31940 
           Speed: 1397 MHz min/max: 1400/2000 MHz boost: enabled Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1397 
           2: 1397 3: 1397 4: 1397 5: 1397 6: 1397 7: 1397 8: 1397 
Graphics:  Device-1: AMD Renoir vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: amdgpu v: kernel bus ID: 04:00.0 
           chip ID: 1002:1636 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: ati,fbdev unloaded: modesetting,radeon,vesa 
           compositor: gnome-shell resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: AMD RENOIR (DRM 3.38.0 5.8.0-rc4-custom LLVM 10.0.0) 
           v: 4.6 Mesa 20.0.8 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: AMD vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 04:00.1 
           chip ID: 1002:1637 
           Device-2: AMD Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor vendor: Hewlett-Packard 
           driver: snd_rn_pci_acp3x v: kernel bus ID: 04:00.5 chip ID: 1022:15e2 
           Device-3: AMD Family 17h HD Audio vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: snd_hda_intel 
           v: kernel bus ID: 04:00.6 chip ID: 1022:15e3 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.8.0-rc4-custom 
Network:   Device-1: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel bus ID: 02:00.0 
           chip ID: 8086:2723 
           IF: wlo1 state: up mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-1: br-66529c8dff06 state: down mac: <filter> 
           IF-ID-2: docker0 state: down mac: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 506.22 GiB used: 131.75 GiB (26.0%) 
           ID-1: /dev/mmcblk0 model: 00000 size: 29.28 GiB serial: <filter> scheme: MBR 
           ID-2: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Intel model: SSDPEKNW512G8H size: 476.94 GiB 
           speed: 31.6 Gb/s lanes: 4 serial: <filter> rev: HPS0 scheme: GPT 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 239.31 GiB used: 131.67 GiB (55.0%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p5 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 45.0 C mobo: 38.0 C gpu: amdgpu temp: 44 C 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 332 Uptime: 19m Memory: 15.07 GiB used: 1.88 GiB (12.5%) Init: systemd 
           v: 245 runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 9.3.0 alt: 8/9 Shell: bash v: 5.0.16 
           running in: gnome-terminal inxi: 3.0.38
```

Comment: Does your suspend work on the 15" 4700?

Comment: I switched to arch which I think is a bit easier to maintain bleeding edge kernels. The suspend was working though sometimes the screen wouldn't resume and I would have to hard reboot it. Also even if it does resume sometimes the mic gets screwed up. Also it didn't appear to be doing a deep sleep either. I have mostly just been disabling suspend until it gets sorted out unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Kernel 5.8rc6 resolved microphone issue in Ubuntu 20.04. Still figuring out how to resolve top speakers. various settings with HDAJackRetask do not resolve. Best I achieved was front L and R and Top R representing L and R, Still looking for help to resolve this one remaining issue.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Mine is now finally working with Archlinux running a custom Kernel with the Kernel Patches supplied from this thread: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/configuring-amd-ryzen-4500u-laptop/144712/43

Its showing up as "ACP Multichannel Input - HP-HPENVYx360Convertible13_ay0xxx-Type1ProductConfigId-876E".